# Город С. С точкой в конце?

Tags: сокращение

Город С. то есть Симферополь. С точкой в конце, так как сокращение? Верно?

Comment: В конце чего точка?

Comment: С. или С без точки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку в мире есть названия городов из одной буквы — г. Э во Франции (от франц. Eu) и г. Е в штате Мон в Мьянме и др., — нельзя, во избежание путаницы, отказываться от точки, которая будет указывать на сокращённое название.